# Does Kotlin have an "enumerate" function like Python?

Tags: list, kotlin, enumerate

In Python I can write:

```
for i, element in enumerate(my_list):
    print(i)          # the index, starting from 0
    print(element)    # the list-element
```

How can I write this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 53):

#### Iterations in Kotlin: Some Alternatives

Like [already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46825821/8073652) said, `forEachIndexed` is a good way to iterate.

**Alternative 1**

The extension function `withIndex`, defined for `Iterable` types, can be used in `for`-each:

```
val ints = arrayListOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

for ((i, e) in ints.withIndex()) {
    println("$i: $e")
}
```

**Alternative 2**

The extension property `indices` is available for `Collection`, `Array` etc., which let's you iterate like in a common `for` loop as known from C, Java etc:

```
for(i in ints.indices){
     println("$i: ${ints[i]}")
}
```

Comment: What about the performance of both is there something important to emphasize?

Answer (score 41):

There is a [`forEachIndexed`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each-indexed.html) function in the standard library:

```
myList.forEachIndexed { i, element ->
    println(i)
    println(element)
}
```

See [@s1m0nw1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46826172/4465208) as well, `withIndex` is also a really nice way to iterate through an `Iterable`.