# How to get the current index in for each Kotlin

Tags: android, for-loop, kotlin

How to get the index in a for each loop? I want to print numbers for every second iteration

For example

```
for (value in collection) {
    if (iteration_no % 2) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

In java, we have the traditional for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < collection.length; i++)
```

How to get the `i`?

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46825787/does-kotlin-have-an-enumerate-function-like-python/46826172#46826172

Answer (score 689, accepted):

In addition to the solutions provided by @Audi, there's also [`forEachIndexed`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each-indexed.html):

```
collection.forEachIndexed { index, element ->
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It works on Arrays and Iterables, what else do you need it to work on?

Comment: Sorry confused with primitive java arrays.

Comment: Any way to use  `break` inside ?

Comment: You can't break from the entire loop, the only similar thing you can do is `return@forEachIndexed` which will essentially serve as a `continue` to skip to the next element. If you need to break, you'd have to wrap it in a function, and use `return` in the loop to return from that enclosing function.

Comment: Using this will prevent you to work with `continue` use @Audi answer if you need such function

Comment: any performance difference for each vs for loop?

Answer (score 245):

Use `indices`

```
for (i in array.indices) {
    print(array[i])
}
```

If you want value as well as index Use `withIndex()`

```
for ((index, value) in array.withIndex()) {
    println("the element at $index is $value")
}
```

Reference: [Control-flow in kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html)

Comment: I think this answers is better because don't needs to learn something else, just the simple for loop +1

Answer (score 73):

Alternatively, you can use the [`withIndex`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/with-index.html) library function:

```
for ((index, value) in array.withIndex()) {
    println("the element at $index is $value")
}
```

> Control Flow: if, when, for, while:
> https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html

Answer (score 41):

try this; for loop

```
for ((i, item) in arrayList.withIndex()) { }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: How can i put a limit for this loop? Like it goes until half or some numbers before end

Comment: @E.Akio One option would be to work with a sub list: `arrayList.subList(0, arrayList.size/2)`.

Answer (score 40):

### Working Example of `forEachIndexed` in Android

**Iterate with Index**

```
itemList.forEachIndexed{index, item -> 
println("index = $index, item = $item ")
}
```

**Update List using Index**

```
itemList.forEachIndexed{ index, item -> item.isSelected= position==index}
```

Answer (score 14):

It seems that what you are really looking for is `filterIndexed`

For example:

```
listOf("a", "b", "c", "d")
    .filterIndexed { index, _ ->  index % 2 != 0 }
    .forEach { println(it) }
```

Result:

```
b
d
```

Comment: also consider using a function reference `.forEach(::println)`

Comment: @KirillRakhman, is using function references preferred style in situations like that? I am new to Kotlin, so I am still figuring this stuff out.

Comment: I tend to use function references whenever possible. When you have more than one parameter, you save a bunch of characters compared to using a lambda. But it's a matter of taste for sure.

Answer (score 13):

Please try this once.

```
yourList?.forEachIndexed { index, data ->
     Log.d("TAG", "getIndex = " + index + "    " + data);
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

[Ranges](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html) also lead to readable code in such situations:

```
(0 until collection.size step 2)
    .map(collection::get)
    .forEach(::println)
```

Comment: alternatively `(0..collection.lastIndex step 2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a variable `counter=0` and increment inside the loop:

```
for (value in collection){//do something then count++ }`
```