# How to Take index of List Item inside the For Loop in Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, for-loop, indexing, kotlin

```
fun forLoopListItems() {
        val items = listOf("apple", "banana", "kiwifruit")
        for (i in items) {
            if (i.equals("banana")) {
              println("position is ${i.indices}")
            }
        }
    }
```

This is My Kotlin code used with For Loop.
I tried to Print Index Curresponding to "banana"
But Result is "System.out: position is 0..5"
How is it Become 0..5 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the current index in for each Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48898102/how-to-get-the-current-index-in-for-each-kotlin)

Answer (score 4):

The [`indices`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/indices.html) method gives you a range, which is `0..5` in this case because it's called on the `String: banana` with a length of 6.

You can instead iterate with indices as follows:

```
items.forEachIndexed { i, element ->
    if (element == "banana") {
        println("position is $i")
    }
}
```

Alternative ways of iterating with indices are listed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46826172/8073652).

I'm not sure if you really want to iterate explicitly though. Maybe it's fine for you to use built-in functions for finding the index of your element:

```
println(items.indexOf("banana"))
```

Comment: usage of -> is find in Many Places ,,why its Used?

Answer (score 1):

There is [`indexOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index-of.html):

> Returns first index of element, or -1 if the collection does not
>   contain element.

and [`lastIndexOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/last-index-of.html):

> Returns last index of element, or -1 if the collection does not contain element.

```
val items = listOf("apple", "banana", "kiwifruit")
val appleIndex = items.indexOf("apple") // 0
val lastAppleIndex = items.lastIndexOf("apple") // 0
val bananaIndex = items.indexOf("banana")  // 1
val orangeIndex = items.indexOf("orange")  // -1
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can iterate with Index using `forEachIndexed` method of Kotlin**

Iterate with Index

```
itemList.forEachIndexed{index, item -> 
println("index = $index, item = $item ")
}
```

Check if item is Banana and print Index

```
itemList.forEachIndexed{ index, item -> {
         if (item.equals("banana")) {println("position is ${index}")}
              }
```